# Formula to print 'X' if comma separated string value = '<value>'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to have **Excel** print 'X" in a table column based on if a specific value is found in a comma separated string given to me from a Microsoft Form.

I removed the characters I don't want, and now my comma separated string is just that, comma separated only.

I have tried a formula where if I search the string and it finds the value I am looking for, it returns to the corresponding table column with 'X'.

Original Output from Microsoft Forms:

```
["ViewPoint","B2W Estimate","Nektar Equipdata"]
```

I have used this formula to strip characters that I don't want/need.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Applications[Applications], "[", ""),"""",""),",",", "),"]","")
```

This is the formula I am trying to use to get the corresponding column to input what I want.

```
=IF([Column7]=(SEARCH("ViewPoint",[Column7])),"X","")
```

Here is the expected and the actual result :

```
Expected Result: "X"
Actual Result: "#NAME?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if i understand your question correctly.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,A4)),"X","-")`

If you want the total number of occurances in the column, you need this **ARRAY Formuly CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

`=SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1;A4:A7))*1)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you get he #NAME? result if the searched item doesn't contain the string of interest, because it is checking "Does myString = #ERR ?"

In addition to the other answer, you could also try:
`IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(...)),"X","-")`